# When Launching Chrome Driver using Specflow - chromedriver.exe file does not exist error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

So I am using Visual Studio and have installed Specflow Extension, Specflow Project and there is a Class Library project which contains a Method to Launch a Chrome Driver.
The test I have written with Specflow is;

```
    LaunchDriver launchDriver = new LaunchDriver() ;

    [Given(@"I Launch a Chrome Driver")]
    public void GivenILaunchAChromeDriver()
    {
        launchDriver.LaunchChrome();
    }
```

The code of LaunchDriver Class is :

```
public class LaunchDriver
{
    public IWebDriver webDriver;

    public void LaunchChrome()
    {
        string PathtoChromeExe = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\";
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver(PathtoChromeExe);
        webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }
}
```

When I try to run this test via Test Explorer, I am seeing the test has failed due to following error

Launch Driver and Navigate to Google.com
Duration: 378 ms

```
  Message: 
    The file C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

  Stack Trace: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The file C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    DriverService.ctor(String servicePath, Int32 port, String driverServiceExecutableName, Uri driverServiceDownloadUrl)
    ChromiumDriverService.ctor(String executablePath, String executableFileName, Int32 port, Uri downloadUrl)
    ChromeDriverService.ctor(String executablePath, String executableFileName, Int32 port)
    ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(String driverPath, String driverExecutableFileName)
    ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(String driverPath)
```

The Chrome driver which I need launching, its filename is chrome.exe in the path I have specified, but for some reason the Specflow or the System is looking for chromedriver.exe to launch which it cannot find.
How do I configure my code to launch the chrome.exe and not chromedriver.exe?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some confusion about "chromedriver" and "chrome".

The file `chrome.exe` is the executable file for Google Chrome, the web browser. The file named `chromedriver.exe` starts a server on your machine which acts as a bridge between your automation code and Google Chrome.

The `ChromeDriver(string)` constructor expects a path to `ChromeDriver.exe` not a path to the web browser executable.

If you need to specify the location of the Google Chrome browser executable, you will need to initialize ChromeDriver with an options object:

```
public void LaunchChrome()
{
    var options = new ChromeDriverOptions()
    {
        BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\"
    };

    webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}
```

This code will use chrome.exe in that specific location, but search for ChromeDriver.exe in your Windows %PATH%. If you need to specify the path to ChromeDriver.exe as well, pass that as a string in the first argument:

```
var options = new ChromeDriverOptions()
{
    BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\"
};

var driverPath = @"C:\path\to\folder\containing\chromedriver";

webDriver = new ChromeDriver(driverPath, options);
```